# DataContract secret behavior?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, datacontract

Every time I meet this attribute, I always see such usage:

```
[DataContract]
class DataTransferObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

And in this example all inherited members should apply DataMember attribute to every property or field, this can lead to VERY clumsy and poilerplate code. But, recently I found (maybe secret feature?) a very elegant way of using it:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class DTOBase
{
}

public class MyDTO : DTOBase
{
    public int Value {get;set;}

    public MyDTO(){} //important part is here
}
```

*Important part: You should **always** explicitly define parameterless constructor, otherwise it won't serialize properly.*

And yeah. It **will** serialize all its public members, no matter how deep will be inheritance, without need to apply attributes to members or class definitions.

Is this somehow documented somewhere (I didn't found)? Because, I were very supprized how much of boilerplate can be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to use `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes if you don't want to, however they give you flexibility in defining what needs to be serialized and how.

I suggest starting with article [Serializable Types on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732.aspx), it has a lot of information how Data Contract serializer works. Here are first 2 paragraphs, proving that you don't need to use attributes:

> By default, the DataContractSerializer serializes all publicly visible
>   types.
>
> All public read/write properties and fields of the type are
>   serialized.  You can change the default behavior by applying the
>   DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute attributes to the types
>   and members This feature can be useful in situations in which you have
>   types that are not under your control and cannot be modified to add
>   attributes. The DataContractSerializer recognizes such "unmarked"
>   types.

The main rules that apply to your case are:

- `DataContract` attribute is not inherited. You can either apply it or not on your base class `DTOBase`, it is ignored in child class `MyDTO`. You can remove `DataContract` attribute from `DTOBase` class and result will be the same.
- If you use `DataContract` attribute on a class, then only members that have `DataMember` attribute will be serialized. This is what happened in class `DataTransferObject` in your first sample.
- If you do not use `DataContract` attribute on a class, then all public members of a class are serialized. This is what happened with your class `MyDTO`.